# how to get PID and State of certain Processes

Tags: linux, debian, ps

I have created a basic shell script that simply counts down from 1000. This is just for testing but could be any application/process.

```
##filename:test.sh##

#!/bin/bash
i=1000; while [ $i -gt 0 ]; do echo $i; i=`expr $i - 1`; sleep 1; done
```

Which I start running thus:

```
sh test.sh
```

I now need to get:
a) the pid of that script, 
b) the state of that script

If I do

```
pidof sh test.sh
```

I get multiple results though.

Running

```
ps aux | grep test.sh
```

I get multiple entries including some that are Terminated (state=T) and one that is `grep test.sh`. 
How can I restrict the `pidof` to just the one(s) I need (assume it is just the one instance that is running)

I also need the state. I tried running:

```
ps aux | grep test.sh | ps -o stat --no-headers
```

but that didn't work. I get the state, but for multiple items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pidof -x test.sh` should give you what you need to get the PID.

From the man page,

> -x     Scripts too - this causes the program to also return process id's of shells running the named scripts.

Here's my test,

```
tony@trinity:~$ ls -l testit.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tony tony 83 Jan  5 14:53 testit.sh
tony@trinity:~$ ./testit.sh
1000
999
998
997
```

meanwhile

```
tony@trinity:~$ ps -ef | grep testit.sh
tony      4233 20244  0 14:58 pts/5    00:00:00 /bin/bash ./testit.sh
tony      4295  3215  0 14:58 pts/6    00:00:00 grep --color=auto testit.sh
```

and then

```
tony@trinity:~$ pidof -x testit.sh
4233
```

Your later query is a common issue, one solution is,

```
ps aux | grep test.sh | grep -v grep
```

which should give you only a single line (assuming `test.sh` is unique).

And lastly, in your final command, you're not just passing a single PID, you're passing a whole line of text, and that's not how `ps` expects to be given a PID anyway (it expects the PID after `-p`).

For example,

```
tony@trinity:~$ ps aux | grep testit.sh
tony      4233  0.1  0.0   4288  1276 pts/5    S+   14:58   0:00 /bin/bash ./testit.sh
tony      5728  0.0  0.0   3476   760 pts/6    S+   15:04   0:00 grep --color=auto testit.sh
```

So we need to grep out the grep, and then only return the pid.

```
tony@trinity:~$ ps aux | grep testit.sh | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'
4233
```

then,

```
tony@trinity:~$ ps -o stat --no-headers -p $(ps aux | grep testit.sh | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')
S+
```

There are probably plenty of less convoluted ways to get there, but I wanted to show the progress.

Comment: That's great cheers. good explanation too.